# Sharepoint REST Api in Java: Unable to access site documents

Tags: java, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to access sharepoint site documents using SP REST API in java. I am able to authenticate and get a response for the below URL

```
http://sharepoint_server_url/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')
```

But I want to get the list of folders and files inside my site. I tried the following URL, but it gives me 401 Unauthorized.

```
http://sharepoint_server_url/sites/mysitename/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')
```

I am using the NTCredentials class, to authenticate. 
Please let me know if

- I have to make some setting in the Sharepoint server for mysite, so that I can access it through API?
- Or, The URL above is wrong, I have to change it?

This is the code used for authentication :

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY),
            new NTCredentials("username", "password", "http://server_DNS", "DOMAIN"));
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

I am sure someone must have done this already. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your use has permission at the root level, but not at the Site level?

Comment: Hi, fixed the issue. I was using an improper domain name. With that, I was able to access the web, but not individual sites.

Comment: Hi @Dharshni, Could you please share complete source code to download a file from sharepoint as i am getting 403 Forbidden error? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look of this project i've created for using the ShareopintRestAPI from java. I decided to make my own implementation as I've struggled a lot with other APIs i found and i was not able to make them work.

You can take a look here

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java